# How to retrieve the permalink for a specific (custom) term?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, terms

I would like to display the list of categories related to particular post?

```
<?php 
while ( $faktory_panes_query->have_posts() ) :
    $faktory_panes_query->the_post();

    $post_id = $post->ID;
    $cat_list = get_the_terms( $post_id,'pane_cat' );
    //print_r($cat_list);
    if(!empty($cat_list)):
        foreach($cat_list as $cat_lists){
            echo "<div id='post-menu'>";
            echo $cat_lists->name."</br>";
            echo "</div>";
        }
    endif;
endwhile;?>
```

i got the categories but the permalinks are not present..How will i get that?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for function `get_term_link`.
Example

```
$my_term_link = get_term_link($cat_lists);
```

Here `$cat_lists` is term object.

[Official Documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_link)